# Where was J's mom in MIB 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black-3

I know the little boy in *Men in Black 3* was J and it's implied that K raised him.  I was fine with that implication until I asked myself... "why didn't J's mother just raise him?"

So,  my question is,  why didn't J's mother just raise him?

Answer (score 22):

I don't think it is actually implied that K raised J. Rather than that, it seems to imply that he **silently looked out for him behind the scenes** his whole life, until he recommended him as an MiB recruit when he was old enough.

If I remember correctly, the movie implied that **the events from the 60s in MiB 3 always happened** (rather than being some kind of new timeline). So J's first actual meeting with K would be when he applies for MiB and becomes his partner in MiB 1. There was **no notion of them knowing each other beforehand**.

So I think the implication there was really that K just became somewhat of a silent guardian to J out of responsibility for his father's death but without ever directly interacting with him. More like keeping an eye on him out of the shadows.

Comment: So... his mother did raise him?

Comment: @Xen2050 It is a possibility. may be J was raised in a shelter, by a priest, by nuns or had foster family. could be any one of'em or something else. There are no other notions about this in the movies

Comment: @Xen2050 I wish I could tell you about who raised J but the last thing I remember about it is a flash of light......

Comment: @NikhilEshvar you've been flashed half then ;)

Comment: First you say the 60s events always happened. Then you say J first met K in the 90s (therefore the 60s events didn't always happen).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean conciously meeting him. He might have seen him as a child for a little moment, but it's not like he was his daddy for 20 years before he aplied for MiB himself.

Comment: Okay - so that's the case no matter whether there is a new timeline or not ;)